# Fantasy-style book cover with merchants and an elephant-sized pack animal

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am remembering a novel from the 80s, I've never read it but the cover was in the vein of [Darrell K. Sweet](https://web.archive.org/web/20110131141102/http://www.sweetartwork.com:80/DKSscienceFictoingallery.html), [Don Maitz](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Don%20Maitz%20book%20covers&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJos_unIzUAhWGHsAKHceJBzYQ_AUICigB&biw=1360&bih=638) or [Michael Whelan](http://www.michaelwhelan.com/gallery/illustration/fantasy/) and featured the gates of a city with merchants are coming and going. One merchant is leading a pack animal that is elephant-sized. *Ring any bells?*

Comment: If you've never read it, how are you going to know when we've identified it?

Comment: @DJClayworth - Post a picture of the cover and the OP will say "***Yup, that's the one***".

Answer (score 7):

This could be *[The Memory of Earth](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92956.The_Memory_of_Earth)* (1993), by Orson Scott Card, with cover art by [Keith Parkinson](https://www.keithparkinson.com/).

[image: The Memory of Earth]

The [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?44027) has a sharper scan of the cover art.

Comment: My eyesight is not the best. Is there really a large pack animal in that picture?

Comment: @user14111 - The pack animal is in the lower right of the picture, heading left through the gate.  The animal and gate have similar colouring, and they blend together.  The animal is twice as tall as the nearby humans; its head, which resembles a gargoyle's, is above the person in the floating chair, and its back is piled high with goods.

Comment: Thank you. As you can imagine, I don't do very well on those "can you find the cat in this picture" puzzles.